# vertical-align:bottom WITH float:left

Tags: css

how could i do `vertical-align:bottom` for some divs that have `float:left`?

you can see the source here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb1su4w2/

---

**this is what i have:** *(every color is a different div)*
[image]

**this is what i want to have:**
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vertical align only works with inline block elements, floated elements ignore the vertical align property.

Update the box class with the following:

```
.box {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width:80px;
}
```

I would make them all inline block elements and remove the whitespace with [one of these techniques](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block).

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9rcnLb8n/

Alternatively you could use [flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with the `align-self: flex-end;` property.

Comment: Yeah, though I would mention it as it is another option if you are working on a project that doesn't have to support the dinosaur browsers :)

Comment: @nickspiel what should I do if there are some float: right; elements as well? I can't change it to display: inline-block;

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
    <div id='a' class='box'>aa</div>
    <div id='b' class='box'>bb</div>
    <div id='c' class='box'>cc</div>
    <div id='d' class='box'>dd</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    width:80px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: inline-block;
}
#a {
    background-color:red;
    height:200px;
}
#b {
    background-color:green;
    height:100px;
}
#c {
    background-color:yellow;
    height:150px;
}
#d {
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
}

#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    display: table;
}
```

In this case don't use:

```
float: left;
```

Instead use:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Check out my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb1su4w2/6/